# Empty variable define in php

Tags: php, variables, declaration

Before doing something with **$error**:

```
$error = NULL;
```

In some script's saw:

```
$error = '';
$error = false;
$error = 0;
```

- Which method is 'better' or maybe it depends in which situation i use
  it ?
- What's your suggestion ?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Depends on your design:

- Are you setting it as an Object in case of error? Use `NULL`.
- Are you setting it to `true` in case of error? Use `false`.
- Are you setting it as a number of some sort in case of error? Use `0`.
- Are you setting it to a string to describe the error? Use `''`.

A better way to indicate errors would be [throwing Exceptions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) though, rather than setting a variable and determine the error according to it.

Comment: What's about an array?

Comment: @Kwadz An empty array, usually.

Comment: It would be great to get some explanation for why each option is preferred. eg Whether it be instructive of the type of the variable. or if it is an optimisation.

Comment: @Lsakurifaisu The preferred option would be to throw an exception regardless. Note that this is an answer from 6 years ago, when Exceptions in PHP were a new exciting thing. C-style error return values are not as common as they used to be (and for good reasons)

Comment: If you want to define an empty array use `$foo = array();`

Comment: @standalone If anything, `[]`, not `array();`, we're not in PHP 5.3 anymore ;)

Answer (score 6):

There is no canonical answer to this question. As long as you use one of these semaphores consistently, you can use anything you want. Because PHP is loosely-typed, all of these values are "falsy" and can be evaluated in a boolean comparison as `FALSE`.

That said, there is more of a difference between the empty string and the others, so I'd stick with `NULL`s and `FALSE`s in this sort of scenario.

Answer (score 5):

1.

```
$v = NULL;

settype($v, 'string');
settype($v, 'int');
settype($v, 'float');
settype($v, 'bool');
settype($v, 'array');

var_dump($v);
```

2.

```
$v = NULL;
var_dump( (string) $v);
var_dump( (int) $v);
var_dump( (float) $v);
var_dump( (bool) $v);
var_dump( (array) $v);
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon the conditions where you need to use the `$error`. Using a `NULL` is what I chose mostly as I deal more with MySQL clauses and all!